# Can having a blocking callback in an asynchronous method cause the UI to hault?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I was just reading an [article](https://blog.sessionstack.com/how-javascript-works-event-loop-and-the-rise-of-async-programming-5-ways-to-better-coding-with-2f077c4438b5) about asynchronous programming and the event loop. During the read he describes that if I call an asynchronous method and pass it a callback, e.g. an `Ajax` request, the web API will deal with an event. The event in this case would be the `Ajax` request receiving a message. When the event is raised it is added to the event queue and when the call stack is empty and the event queue are being called, the callback from the event is called.

Given that the callback of the event queue is placed onto the call stack, which is on the UI thread, would that not mean that having a substantially long callback would result in the UI being blocked? Was asynchronous programming not meant to prevent these types of problems?

Edit: I just realized I could test my theory by opening the browser and testing it myself by creating,

```
setTimeout(function(){
   while(true){}
}, 500)
```

When typing this, the UI will freeze.

Does this imply I am correct? An asynchronous call and asynchronous code can still freeze the UI?

Comment: An asynchronous call does not mean that any execution present in that is completely cut off from the main thread. It only means that, the order of events get changed but eventually everything ends in the same UI thread so yes, if the callback function does something like the example given by you,then the UI would obv be frozen.

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt Thanks, I was thinking about Threads for a while, how Threads can switch between each other and not block the UI. So when it came to async I was looking into it since this was single threaded.

Comment: @user12388651 Synchronous or asynchronous, every piece of code in javascript will eventually run on main thread. Check the detailed answer that I have provided for more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your intuition is correct.

Because javascript is single-threaded, any work done during a turn of the event loop will block the UI.

The advantage of async calls like `Ajax`, is that your script doesn't actually need to do any work while it waits for a network response. It is better to yield control while waiting, freeing the UI until the Ajax call comes back and then you can do something.

As an example, you can send an Ajax request in sync mode, and it will block while waiting

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous code will eventually execute on main thread. So while the asynchronous code will be executing on main thread, main thread will freeze. That means no other code can run. Asynchronous code will not start to execute right away. It will wait until it's time has come, and when the time comes for the asynchronous code to execute it will execute in **synchronous manner**.

Let me come to the example you have provided.

```
setTimeout(function(){
   while(true){}
}, 500)
```

The callback you have provided to setTimeout will not execute before 500 millisecond have passed. When the waiting time will over, javascript engine will load the callback function to main thread for executing. As it is an infinite loop, main thread will be blocked for infinite amount of time. No other code will have any chance to be executed.